# Formula that looks for values in two columns in order and calculates the average in the third column

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

So I have three columns, A (Country), B (Status), and C (transit time). Below is an example:

```
Country         status          transit time    
Slovakia        Transit         2   
Hong Kong       Delivered       1   
New Zealand     Transit         2   
Barbados        Transit         2   
Peru            Transit         2   
Ecuador         Transit         2   
Greece          Transit         2   
New Zealand     Transit         4
```

I was hoping to see if there are two formulas. The first formula would match Column A and return the average in Column C as the value. Using the example above, if I wanted to know the average transit time for New Zealand (which is 3 days in this example). The other formula I was looking for is one that return the value of all shipments over the average transit time (that was found before). For example, I know the average transit time to New Zealand is 3 days, but I also want to know how many shipments exceeded the average 3 days (in this example, it would be 1 shipment).

Comment: AVERAGEIFS() will return the average using conditionals.  Then it is a matter of using COUNTIFS() to return the count using the value returned as one of the conditionals.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but I'm still confused. What I'm trying to do is set up a formula that will look  look for New Zealand in Column A. If true, then it will sum up the total transit time (shown in Column C).

Comment: Yes and AVERAGEIFS() will do that.  Or SUMIFS() if you want to sum.  Google those functions.  Microsoft has videos and walk throughs on how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample sheet with the method that Scott identified in the comments:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mKwLtwnOZaWzj2zWV71_hKVg76GRB_4ou_4KrHhDuxw/edit?usp=sharing

The first formula, in F2, is like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A$2:A$9,E2,C$2:C$9)
```

which calculates the average transit time for the shipments to each country.

The second formula, in G2, is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$9,E2,C$2:C$9,">"&F2)
```

which counts the number of shipments to each country where the transit time is greater that the average.

See here:
[image]

Let us know if you are still having an issue using the two functions Scott suggested.